# How to configure postfix to use one virtual alias file per domain?

Tags: postfix

In Exim I have one file per domain where the **filename** itself is used to determine the domain for the aliases.

For example, I'd have a file named **example.org** with contents like this:

```
foo:      somelocaluser
```

This causes mail to `foo@example.org` to be delivered to `somelocaluser`.

---

In **Postfix** the common setup is to use the file named `virtual` and repeat the domain for every local part over and over again:

```
foo@example.org: somelocaluser
bar@example.org: somelocaluser
```

**How can I achieve my Exim-style setup in Postfix and thus avoid the repetiton?**

Answer (score 3):

### No, you can't

Your desired feature doesn't exist in postfix *hash* table. Postfix database lookup always get key from the entry of the file, it can't mix it with the file name.

More info: [Postfix Lookup Table Overview](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html)

---

However, you can achieve the same with little scripting. The script should loop all files then append the file name string to first column of the entry then combine it.

The ugly script like this should do the job fine

```
for file in `find /tmp/mapfiles -type f -maxdepth 1`; do
    grep : "$file" | while read line; do
        mykey=$(echo "$line" | cut -d':' -f1)
        myvalue=$(echo "$line" | cut -d':' -f2)
        filename=$(basename "$file")
        echo "${mykey}@${filename}: ${myvalue}"
    done
done
```

Don't forget to `postmap` or `postalias` the output file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there at least a way that allows me to add new domains on the fly without explicitly having to name them in the configuration. A wildcard - maybe something like `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_files/*` ?

Comment: I think postfix configuration parser doesn't support that :(

Comment: As my files are named like the virtual domain name they refer to, here is the less ugly script :) `for file in /path/to/virtual/files/* ; do sed "s,:,@$file,g" $file ; done > /etc/postfix/virtual`

Comment: Should be `cd /path/to/virtual/files/ && for file in * ; do sed "s,:,@$file,g" $file ; done > /etc/postfix/virtual`